# Why I am unable to import dronekit?

Tags: raspbian, modules

I have been following [this website](https://dronekit-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quick_start.html).
I have installed dronekit and dronekit-sitl as by using the following commands.

```
pip install dronekit
pip install dronekit-sitl
```

But the problem is that , when I import this module in my python script it says MODULE NOT FOUND.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ \python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Jul 14 2021, 08:11:37)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dronekit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dronekit
>>>
```

Whenever I use pip install it states we successfully installed .
Now I have used the following commands.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python -m dronekit
/usr/bin/python: No module named dronekit
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python2 -m dronekit
/usr/bin/python2: No module named dronekit
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -m dronekit
/usr/bin/python3: No module named dronekit.__main__; 'dronekit' is a package and cannot be directly executed                                                 cannot be directly executed
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Please help me how to tackle this problem.

Thanking you.

Comment: "Please help me how to tackle this problem" don't waste your (and our) time with 6 year old posts.

Comment: @Milliways I would be highly obliged if you provide me the link.

Comment: have you tried from dronekit install * or from dronekit import connect, VehicleMode?

Comment: @SteveRobillard No sir.